# How to use listkeys function in an ARM Template with Event Hub

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-eventhub, azure-keyvault, azure-rm-template

I have an event hub that looks like this:
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I have successfully done it for service bus, but only for the high level *RootManageSharedAccessKey*.

However with Event Hub I want the primary connection string for the *SendOnly* shared access policy.

I have tried many combinations but I when I deploy the deployment cant find the SendOnly shared access policy.

Here is the json for my SendOnly shared access policy.

[image]

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The final working ARM template code was:

```
[listkeys(resourceId('Microsoft.EventHub/namespaces/eventhubs/authorizationRules', variables('ehub').name, parameters('eventhubs_myaccountevents_name'), 'SendOnly'), parameters('eventhubs_api_version')).primaryConnectionString]
```

Note that instead of this:

```
Microsoft.Eventhub/namespaces/authorizationRules
```

I had to use this:

```
Microsoft.EventHub/namespaces/eventhubs/authorizationRules
```

Here is the sample I used:
https://github.com/pascalnaber/EnterpriseARMTemplates/blob/6babc4d3e65f10f999bb144a1d616ccb2a085e9d/templates/resources/Microsoft.Eventhub/azuredeploy.json

Answer (score 7):

use this to get the connection string:

```
"[listkeys(resourceId('Microsoft.Eventhub/namespaces/authorizationRules',
  parameters('name'), 'RootManageSharedAccessKey'),
  '2017-04-01').primaryConnectionString]"
```

you cannot split it across lines, i've done that for sake of readibility

Comment: But that's the root connection string. I need the send only

Comment: replace `'RootManageSharedAccessKey'` with `'SendOnly'`?

Comment: I also had to add another resourceid section in between namespaces and authorizationRules:
[listkeys(resourceId('Microsoft.EventHub/namespaces/eventhubs/authorizationRules', variables('ehub').name, parameters('eventhubs_myaccountevents_name'), 'SendOnly'), parameters('eventhubs_api_version')).primaryConnectionString]

Comment: well, you could at least upvote my answer, as its the right one, technically  ;)

Comment: Sorry man  I have done that now. Are you saying yours works as well if I just replace RootConnectionShar.... If so why do they both work?

Comment: interesting, i wasnt awake enough ;) I didnt test it with `'SendOnly'`, tbh, I assumed it would work like that, but looking at your answer now, it might be that it wont work.

Comment: I'll try your suggestion just for fun tomorrow

Comment: I tried youway, with just replacing the RootManageSharedAccessKey with SendOnly and that failed. Then I added /eventhubs in here:
/ Microsoft.Eventhub/namespaces/eventhubs/authorizationRules
and
The event hub name in as well so the final result was this:
[listkeys(resourceId('Microsoft.Eventhub/namespaces/eventhubs/authorizationRules', variables('ehub').name, parameters('eventhubs_myaccountevents_name'), 'SendOnly'), parameters('eventhubs_api_version')).primaryConnectionString]
Which now works. 

So im afraid your way doesn't work. 
Russ

Answer (score 3):

This is how I solved it (including creating the authorization rule):

#### Define the variables:

```
...
"variables": {
    "eventHubNamespaceName": "myehubns",
    "eventHubName": "myehub",
    "eventhubSendAuthorizationRuleName": "SendOnly",
    "eventHubSendRuleId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.EventHub/namespaces/eventhubs/authorizationRules', variables('eventHubNamespaceName'),variables('eventHubName'), variables('eventhubSendAuthorizationRuleName'))]"
}
```

#### Create the Authorization Rule:

```
...
"resources": [{
        "apiVersion": "2017-04-01",
        "name": "[variables('eventhubSendAuthorizationRuleName')]",
        "type": "authorizationRules",
        "dependsOn": [
            "[concat('Microsoft.EventHub/namespaces/', variables('eventHubNamespaceName'),'/eventhubs/',variables('eventHubName'))]"
        ],
        "properties": {
            "rights": [
                "Send"
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

#### Retrieve the primary Connection String of the previous created rule:

```
"EventHubConnectionstring": "[listkeys(variables('eventHubSendRuleId'), '2017-04-01').primaryConnectionString]"
```